# PHP - The coordinates of image not returned correctly with Imagick

Tags: php, rotation, coordinates, imagick, image-rotation

I want the eyes in the image to be horizontal

```
$rightEyeY = 446;
$rightEyeX = 625;
$leftEyeY = 433;
$leftEyeX = 733;

// Get middle point of two eyes
$y = $rightEyeY - $leftEyeY;
$x = $rightEyeX - $leftEyeX;

$angle = rad2deg(atan2($y, $x)) - 180; // -6.8 degrees

$manager = new ImageManager(['driver' => 'imagick']);
$image = $manager->make('image.jpg')->rotate($angle);
$a = $angle * pi() / 180.0;
$cosa = cos($a);
$sina = sin($a);
$x = $x * $cosa - $y * $sina; // This one calculates x of the middle point not each eye.
$y = $x * $sina + $y * $cosa; // This one calculates y of the middle point not each eye.
```

I want those variables at the top

```
FROM:
```

rightEyeY = 446

rightEyeX = 625

```
TO:
```

rightEyeY = 695

rightEyeX = 510

When I rotate it in Photoshop by `-6.86` degrees, it rotates counterclockwise. But in Imagick, it rotates clockwise when using `-6.86`.

The original image (RightEye Point: 625x446):

[image: original-625x446]

The rotated image in Photoshop (RightEye Point: 640x432):

[image: photoshop-640x432]

The rotated image with Imagick (RightEye Point: 695x510):

[image: imagick-695x510]

After rotation, the width/height of the image is changing. So the formula for getting the right eye point doesn't give us the exact point.

How can I fix it and get the right eye point?